# Creating a folder with '%' in folder name returns 400 Bad Request when folder already exists

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api, 2019

My aim is to create a folder with % in folder name if it doesn't exist in SP Server-2019 using REST.

```
 POST http://<site>/_api/web/folders

{
  "__metadata": {
    "type": "SP.Folder"
  },
  "ServerRelativeUrl": "/SP 2019/Folder%"
}
```

But this is creating a Folder%25 instead of Folder%.
So, after reading [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/supporting-and-in-file-and-folder-with-the-resourcepath-api), i am using:

```
POST http://<site>/_api/web/folders/AddUsingPath(decodedurl='Path')
```

> Note: This successfully creates a folder with name '%' if it does not
>   exist.

The issue i am running into is the api returns 400 Bad Request in two cases: 
a) The folder already exists. 
b) The URL is malformed.

I need to differentiate between the two. Or if folder creation if possible using some other api call, that would be helpful!

Ref: [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61205613/10091625)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using encodeURI and encodeURIComponent, sample usage [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540753/should-i-use-encodeuri-or-encodeuricomponent-for-encoding-urls). What it does is it will encode the uri to satisfy the server request with the right url format.

Hope the concept helps, Happy Coding!

Comment: I have tried sending encoded url in the path. But it didnt help.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify the folder using `%25` actually. This will be decoded into `%`!

```
POST http://<site>/_api/web/folders/AddUsingPath(decodedurl='Folder%25')
```

Note: This will create the folder in the root of the site. You probably want to include a library in the url.
Here is my test that created a folder successfully:

```
    let ctx = this.props.context;
    let options: ISPHttpClientOptions = {};
    let folder = "Shared%20Documents/Folder%25";
    let url = `/sites/Playground/_api/web/Folders/AddUsingPath(decodedurl='${folder}')`; 
    ctx.spHttpClient.post(url, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1, options).then((res:SPHttpClientResponse) => {
      res.text().then(text => {
        console.log(text);
      });
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

[image]

Comment: I think i haven't the question clearly. I am doing the steps as you suggested. **My issue is that when the folder is already present, it gives `400 Bad Request` Error**. Which is a client side error. The earlier call (the one with metadata Ref: Question above) returns `201 Created` even when the folder exists.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the folder already exists before creating folder.

```
http://site url/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativePath(decodedUrl='folder name')
```

If the request returns a value, it means that the folder already exists.

For SharePoint Online ,you could try to use Microsoft Graph API to create folder.
Here is the document for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-post-children?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/drive/root:/{path}:/children
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/drive/root/children
```

Comment: Hi! Yes that would be the last option. I don't really want to double the number of calls made.

Comment: The endpoint in your referenced issue ‘POST http://<site>/_api/web/folders’  will not create a new folder when the folder has existed.But as you know,this endpoint requires you to deal with special characters.

Comment: Yes, was just searching for a way that tells me clearly that the folder already exists instead of a `400 Bad Req` error.